# Lyrics of Needles written by System of a Down

Tags: lyrics

At the end of the song, many website say the lyrics are :

> Just waiting for the **tomb**  Of some old dying man?

I always thought it was **thuum** instead of **tomb** but how can I check ? Is there a good enough source to solve this situation ?

Also, I sometime see **tune** which is not absurd either.

Comment: What's a "thuum"???

Comment: @Tetsujin thuum is like vital energy breath I guess

Comment: I think the meaning is "sitting there waiting to die".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of websites on the internet that have the lyrics of Needles like:

https://genius.com/System-of-a-down-needles-lyrics

and

https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/32799/

even if you google 'system of a down needles lyrics' Google provides you with the lyrics.

The word is Tomb

Here's a picture of the booklet including the lyrics

[image]

Comment: A picture of the lyrics in the booklet is my only suitable source. The reason I asked is because I don't trust websites

Comment: @vdolez I am editing my answer. There is no reason not to trust internet lyric sites as long as it's written in 4-5 of them I think you are safe.

Comment: Thanks ! Did you took the picture or found it on the internet ? If the later, I'd be curious to know how you found it 'cause I couldn't. Now I feel a bit sad for having been wrong :(

Comment: @vdolez I own the album. This is my pic ;)

Comment: Internet lyrics are by no means trustworthy and neither are lyrics printed in albums even. In this case it seems accurate and the song is likely yet another song about doing drugs(?) with the tapeworm symbolizing addiction. Although when performing it live they sometimes randomly change the lyrics to other weird stuff. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kkrs2IdlH4I 2:12 What are they even singing "needle in my head"? "psycho/cycle/sickle in my head"? Heh...